# SSIS Deployment Error: DataReader Issue When Executing Truncate Table SQL Command Task from SSISDB in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, deployment, ssis, sqlcommand, datareader

I have a package containing a SQL Command task that truncates a table in SQL Server. When I executed it in the Visual Studio platform, the execution was successful. However, upon deployment and attempting to execute it from the SSISDB in SQL Server, I encountered the following error:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first. (Microsoft.Data.SqlClient)"

```
Program Location:
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ValidateConnectionForExecute(SqlCommand command)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ValidateConnectionForExecute(String method, SqlCommand command)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlComma
```

I only have the SQL Command task in my package.
versions:
Visual Studio Community : 2022
SQL Derver developer : 2022
SSMS : 2019